# Drag and Drop in CKEditor integration (jQuery UI dialog mode)

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, ckeditor, elfinder

This "How to" https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-CKEditor-%28jQuery-UI-dialog-mode%29 is good to me except that I get an error when I try to drag and drop a file (image) in the editor.

I'm using lastest CKEditor and latest elFinder.

The error message is editor is just "Can not upload", in my browser it says 2 errors:

1)    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
    at window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.dialog.setValueOf (ckeditor.js:574)
    at main.ckedialog.js:93
    at HTMLImageElement. (main.ckedialog.js:63)
    at HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLImageElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

```
2)Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
at a. (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/plugins/filetools/plugin.js?t=H4PF:7:418)
at a.h (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/ckeditor.js:11:178)
at a.window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/ckeditor.js:13:32)
at a.window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/ckeditor.js:14:225)
at k.upload (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/plugins/filetools/plugin.js?t=H4PF:10:286)
at k. (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/plugins/filetools/plugin.js?t=H4PF:9:227)
at k.a.(anonymous function) (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/ckeditor.js:12:91)
at k.h (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/ckeditor.js:11:178)
at k.window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/ckeditor.js:13:32)
at k.changeStatus (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/plugins/filetools/plugin.js?t=H4PF:13:72)
```

Do you have any idea ? As you can imagine I am not a great developer ...

Thanx a lot !